# Accessing in memory assembly

Tags: c#, memory

I am looking at creating and dynamically compiling an assembly in memory from serialized code. Is it possible to dump or access the memory to gain access to the code of the assembly?

Comment: So you have C# code you'd like to compile in your program? Will this program just run on your computer or the computer of others as well?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you create the assembly.For example, if you use the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx), you can set [CompilerParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx) that will save the assembly in memory or to a file. Or both. You could then read the output file.

You could also [define a dynamic assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xtysk39.aspx) and then save it to disk.

In either case, you can access the code and other information in the assembly using reflection (i.e. [System.Reflection.Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx)).